# How is possible in TSQL select * from @temp not return error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE  @Unitati TABLE (ID INT,Nume VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @Unitati (ID,NUME) VALUES(1,'A')
    INSERT INTO @Unitati (ID,NUME) VALUES(2,'B')
    INSERT INTO @Unitati (ID,NUME) VALUES(3,'C')
    INSERT INTO @Unitati (ID,NUME) VALUES(4,'D')
    INSERT INTO @Unitati (ID,NUME) VALUES(5,'E')

DECLARE  @UnitatiDetalii TABLE (IDUnitate INT,Judet VARCHAR(100),Observatii VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(1,'SB','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(1,'VL','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(1,'AR','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(1,'AB','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(2,'AR','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(2,'AB','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(2,'CJ','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(3,'AR','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(3,'DJ','')
    INSERT INTO @UnitatiDetalii (IDUnitate,Judet,Observatii) VALUES(4,'IS','')

--SELECT * FROM @Unitati
--SELECT * FROM @UnitatiDetalii
```

This return error:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT IDUnitate 
 FROM @Unitati 
 WHERE Nume LIKE 'A'
```

This Work but `IDUnitate` not exists in  @Unitati table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @UnitatiDetalii 
WHERE IDUnitate 
IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT IDUnitate 
     FROM @Unitati 
     WHERE Nume LIKE 'A'
   )
```

Why?

Comment: `IDUnitate ` doesn't exist in first table `@Unitati`, hence the error

Comment: Because `Subquery` can refer `outer query` columns

Answer (score 0):

The first query fails because the column doesn't exist in the table.  The second query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT ud.* 
FROM @UnitatiDetalii ud
WHERE ud.IDUnitate IN (SELECT DISTINCT ud.IDUnitate 
                       FROM @Unitati u
                       WHERE u.Nume LIKE 'A'
                      )
```

In other words, the reference is to the column in the *outer* table.  Here is a good lesson:  *Always* qualify column names.  That way, you won't get an error.

In addition, the `distinct` is unnecessary in an `in`.  You probably want:

```
SELECT ud.* 
FROM @UnitatiDetalii ud
WHERE ud.IDUnitate IN (SELECT u.ID
                       FROM @Unitati u
                       WHERE u.Nume LIKE 'A'
                      )
```

Comment: is not more efficient to use distinct?

Comment: @TotPeRo . . . Not at all.  It should be ignored.  If it is not ignored in this context, then there will be additional wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Subquery` can refer `outer query` columns.

`@UnitatiDetalii` has `IDUnitate` column which can be referred in `subquery`. Even though you don't have `IDUnitate` column in `@Unitati` table it will be referred from outer query so won't get any error.